# What's the most elegant way to call function in __init__ if keywords set to true

Tags: python

I've got the following class which takes in a couple of arguments and keywords. Depending on whether these keywords are True or not, several self functions are then called.

Is there a more elegant way to do this?

```
class DFSetter:

    def __init__(self, doc_dict, styles, **kwargs):
        self.styles = styles
        df = FormatDF(doc_dict, styles)
        self.no_formatting = df.no_formatting
        self.bold = kwargs.get('bold', True)
        self.double = kwargs.get('double', True)
        self.justify = kwargs.get('justify', True)
        self.caps = kwargs.get('caps', True)
        self.table = kwargs.get('table', True)
        self.pStyle = kwargs.get('pStyle', True)
        self.br = kwargs.get('br', True)
        self.shade = kwargs.get('shade', True)
        self.top_bottom = kwargs.get('top_bottom', True)
        self.spcBf = kwargs.get('spcBf', True)

        self.switches = {}
        self.df = df.make_df()

        if self.bold:
            self.set_bold_under()
        if self.double:
            self.set_double_line()
        if self.justify:
            self.set_justify()
        if self.caps:
            self.set_all_caps()
        if self.table:
            self.set_table()
        if self.pStyle:
            self.set_pStyle()
        if self.br:
            self.set_br()
        if self.shade:
            self.set_shd()
        if self.top_bottom:
            self.set_top_bottom()
        if self.spcBf:
            self.set_spcBf()
```

Comment: What do these `set_*` methods do? If they're doing a similar job, you might be able to transform them into a single function that takes the name as an argument. Then you can iterate through `kwargs` and call the method for any kwarg set to True.

Comment: Hi @MohammedFarahmand - all of the set_* methods do something slightly different so can't be combined as one unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set up a dictionary in the `__init__` body that links properties to methods. This also allows you to skip the iteration over `kwargs`, since you just iterate over the dictionary instead.

```py
class DFSetter(object):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.bold = kwargs.get("bold", True)

        d = {self.bold: self.function}
        for property, function in d.items():
            if property:
                function()

    def function(self):
        print("0")
```

Even better is to just remove the properties altogether and use strings instead. This allows you to completely ignore the iteration over `kwargs` for the relevant properties.
You can still set `self.bold` by using `setattr`.

```py
class DFSetter(object):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):

        d = {"name": self.function}
        for property, function in d.items():
            t = kwargs.get(property, True)
            setattr(self, property, t)
            if t:
                function()

    def function(self):
        print("0")
```

Finally, I would like to add that, while it is possible to adopt the above solution, sometimes verbosity is good to have. The code above can be quite unclear, and, depending on your needs, might make your software less maintainable.

Comment: Thanks - that's really helpful